# Creating a list with elements count dependable from the another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

Title may not be as accurate as I'd want it to. I'll show it to you using an example:

```
List<int> anotherList = new List<int>();
[0] 3
[1] 6
[2] 2
[3] 3
[4] 2
[5] 2
[6] 1
```

The `List` I want to create should contain elements multiplied by the elements in `anotherList`.

For example:

```
List<int> newList = new List<int>();
[0] 3
[1] 3
[2] 3
[3] 6
[4] 6
[5] 6
[6] 6
[7] 6
[8] 6
[9] 2
[10] 2
[11] 3
[12] 3
[13] 3
[14] 2
[15] 2
[16] 2
[17] 2
[18] 1
```

I know this list may seem completely useless for anyone but i really need it to move on with my program. Really would appreciate the help with this one!

Comment: i can't understand what are you trying to do

Comment: Have you tried anything? It seems an easy task with a simple foreach loop

Comment: Doesnt matter. Already got a solution from the first answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Linq`'s [`Enumerable.Repeat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb348899(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<int> newList = otherList
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, x))
    .ToList();
```

***The [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx)*** extension method takes [`IEnumerable<T>`s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) selected with a given predicate and flattens them into one [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx). <sub>*(Not necessarily the same `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` that the method was invoked for!)*</sub>

***The [`Enumerable.Repeat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb348899(v=vs.110).aspx)*** method, receives the amount of times to repeat a certain `object` and returns an `IEnumerable` of that `object` repeated.

Comment: `SelectMany` *doesn't* take an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` - it takes an `IEnumerable<TSource>` and a `Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>`.

Comment: It's still not great - it sounds like it's taking a sequence of `T`s and flattening it to... a sequence of `T`s. The bit where each `T` is projected to a subsequence is important. (See how I've described it in my answer.)

Comment: Yeah, Trying to make it easy to understand for those who don't understand `Linq` without damaging the technical accuracy of the answer is sometimes hard haha... rewrote...

Answer (score 10):

LINQ makes this easy with [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Enumerable.Repeat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348899(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var result = input.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, x)).ToList();
```

The `SelectMany` is a flattening operation: for each input in the original sequence, generate a new sequence using the given projection... and the overall result is a sequence which contains all those "subsequences" as one flat sequence.

From there, you just need the projection - which in your case is "for an element `x`, the result is `x`, `x` times". That's easily done with `Enumerable.Repeat(x, x)`.

Comment: Thanks but already implemented what @Tamir Vered suggested :)

Comment: @goliatpiotr: Well they're exactly the same solution, just indented differently  and with different names :)